# Extract values from stdout output using Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am running a command to get the status of tomcat and registering it in a variable. How do i extract the specific output of that command and put it in a variable to check further

Play -

```
- name: Check the State og tomcat service
   shell: "svcs tomcat"
   register: tomcat_status

 - name: Show captured processes
   debug:
     msg: "{{ tomcat_status.stdout_lines|list }}"
```

The output of the above is -

```
 server1 ok: {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": [
        "STATE          STIME    FMRI",
        "online         20:11:48 svc:/network/tomcat:tomcat"
    ]
}
```

How do i extract the value of STATE here? I want to know if it's online or disabled or shutdown etc.

NOTE - Output with -vvvv

```
 server1 done: {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "svcs tomcat",
    "delta": "0:00:00.025711",
    "end": "2020-05-11 12:43:43.323017",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "svcs tomcat",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": false
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2020-05-11 12:43:43.297306",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "STATE          STIME    FMRI\nonline         20:11:48 svc:/network/tomcat:tomcat",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "STATE          STIME    FMRI",
        "online         20:11:48 svc:/network/tomcat:tomcat"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the [`service_facts` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html) if your system supports it and tomcat is registered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `debug` about, `tomcat_status.stdout_lines` is a list (you don't need the `|list` filter here because it's already a list) that looks like:

```
[
  "STATE          STIME    FMRI",
  "online         20:11:48 svc:/network/tomcat:tomcat"
]
```

To get the `STATE` value, you need the first field from the second line.  So:

```
- set_fact:
    tomcat_state: "{{ tomcat_status.stdout_lines.1.split().0 }}"
```

That takes the second line (`tomcat_status.stdout_lines.1`) then splits it on whitespace (`.split()`), and then takes the first value (`.0`).

Here's a complete test:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    tomcat_status:
      stdout_lines:
        - "STATE          STIME    FMRI"
        - "online         20:11:48 svc:/network/tomcat:tomcat"

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        tomcat_state: "{{ tomcat_status.stdout_lines.1.split().0 }}"

    - debug:
        var: tomcat_state
```

Running that playbook results in:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tomcat_state": "online"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The above solution worked for me. I have one more query. Let me know if it needs to be another question.

Can i loop around this variable with some pause/sleep? I mean the current status is "Online" and it goes to "maintenence" then "disabled". Can i loop something like every 10 seconds to check and once the status goes to "disabled", then continue with the rest of the playbook.

Comment: I will put up another one. Tried searching on google but couldn't find anything.